# Why its need to use trunking when using etherchannel?

Tags: trunk, etherchannel

what's the reason to use trunking by using the 2 below commands:

1. switchport trunk encap dot1q
2. change the mode to trunk

between EtherChannel ports

the second question why to make native vlan under etherchannel interface

Answer (score 1):

(VLAN) trunking and Etherchannels are entirely different things.

VLAN trunking allows multiple VLANs to be carried by a single (logical) link. Without VLAN tagging and trunking, each VLAN would require a dedicated link between switches. Today, IEEE 801.2Q tags are commonly used to mark frames from/to individual VLANs. A single VLAN, dubbed *native* may remain untagged on a trunk.

Etherchannel is a Cisco-proprietary *link aggregation* protocol. Alternatives include IEEE LACP (802.1AX) or static aggregation without a protocol. Link aggregation allows you to combine multiple physical links to increase the available bandwidth.

Both methods may be combined to create an aggregated, trunked link.